# Какие расширения и дополнения для Visual Studio используете ?

Tags: visual-studio

Я сам пользуюсь 2012 студией, C# - resharper, indent guides.

Comment: Прошу уточнить - для какой именно студии? И для какого из включенных в нее языковых средств интересуют дополнения-расширения?

Comment: Я пользуюсь Ultimate update 3. Пишу на C#, соответственно было бы интересно для таких настроек узнать дополнения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. ReSharper - без него, как без рук
2. Indent Guides (мелочь, а приятно)
3. NuGet - сокращает число рутинных действий при добавлении в проект различных библиотек

Ну а еще что-то полезное (и, между прочим, бесплатное) можно вынести для себя из [этого](http://www.gotdotnet.ru/blogs/sharomank/7567/) списка

Answer (score 4):

Для C++ рекомендую обратиться в сторону VisualAssist.

А так, лично я никакими дополнениями не пользуюсь. Только хардкор, только оригинал!

Comment: У меня вот получается так, что VisualAssist и встроенный анализатор перестают работать:
1) После долгой работы.(например через 2-3 часа уже не переходит по ссылке туда где должна быть объявлена функция/класс)
2) В случаи очень большой вложенности include(3-6).
3) После частых перекомпиляций всего проекта.
4) Если пути к файлам include объявлены на русском.

Это нормально? Там нельзя установить настройки на более высокую производительность?

Answer (score 3):

[JetBrains ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)

Comment: А с с++ решарпер работает? То-то же!

Comment: А разве вопрошающий как-нибудь указал, что ему для С++? Вопрос был помечен меткой Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую

http://vswebessentials.com/

оччень полезная штука

Answer (score 2):

пишу на `C++`

- Visual Assist (выделение текста и много чего ещё)
- Indent Guides (вертикальные линейки)

попробовал и выкинул:

- Elastic Tabstops
- devColor

Answer (score 1):

- ReSharper, ReSharper C++, dotCover
- Intel Parallel Studio (Cluster)
- CUDA Toolkit
- IncrediBuild

Answer (score 1):

- [Visual F# Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/136b942e-9f2c-4c0b-8bac-86d774189cff) - необходимый набор инструментов для работы с F#
- [Editor Guidelines](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0fbf2878-e678-4577-9fdb-9030389b338c/) - позволяет не писать выражения в 3-4 экрана ноутбука, если сидишь за ultra-wide монитором
- [Hide Main Menu](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bdbcffca-32a6-4034-8e89-c31b86ad4813) - экономит место на экране
- [VSColorOutput](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f4d9c2b5-d6d7-4543-a7a5-2d7ebabc2496) - расцветка стандартного окна Output студии, видно, что происходит при билде. Позволяет остановить билд при первой ошибке, что очень полезно в больших солюшнах
- [TestDriven.Net](http://www.testdriven.net/) - позволяет запускать тесты мышкой из студии (не у всех есть решарпер)